# Migrating musics from Windows Media Player to Apple Music

Tags: music, metadata

I've recently moved from Windows to macOS, and I'm trying to import my local music library into the Music app installed on macOS Big Sur.

I have about 30k mp3 files that I've star-rated over a decade, and I'm trying to bring those ratings to Music. I noticed that WMP stores the rating in an id3 tag named `RATING WMP`. I tried rating a track in the music app and then dumping the file's metadata to find the proper tag to programatically update them, but it seems like Music is not storing any data in the metadata.

Are the Music data stores anywhere else? I tried looking at `/Library/Application Support/` and `~/Library/Application Support/` but there was no folder associated with Music.

Any hint regarding this matter is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think Apple Music/iTunes stores that in the music file itself. If you lose the library.itl for any reason, you also lose all the ratings - so I'm guessing that's where they're stored. The itl file is a tough nut to crack; well above my paygrade, sorry.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. Do you know where the file is located? I couldn't find it via search.

Comment: It's in ~/Music/ [which is /HD/Users/You/Music] then used to be in iTunes, idk the name of the directory since iTunes became 'Music'. I have no idea what that file might open in, it's a database. If you're going to play around with it, duplicate it first. If it breaks, it will rebuild from scratch.